# Assigning onclick event to multiple submenus using Javscript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menu, dropdown

I've been trying to add a dropdown menu functionality using Javascript to a website on certain submenus with a certain class under a specific menu ID only.
It is a wordpress website, which means I need it to be dynamic depending on how many submenus you add on the backend platform.
So to fix that I count how many submenus I have and try to apply an onclick event to each one of them, however the issue is that regardless of which submenu I click, only the last submenu is working (shows/hides it's submenus), which in this case is the Extra submenu.

```
    function newStoreid(){

    document.querySelectorAll('.sidr-class-mega-indicator').forEach(function(a) {
        a.remove()
    })

    var subMenusPrimary = document.getElementById('sidr-id-mega-menu-item-81').querySelectorAll('.sidr-class-mega-menu-item-has-children'); 
    var subMenusPrimaryCount = subMenusPrimary.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < subMenusPrimaryCount; i++) {
        console.log("Primary: " + subMenusPrimary[i].id);
        var elementoSinal = document.getElementById(subMenusPrimary[i].id).getElementsByClassName("sidr-class-mega-menu-link")[0]; //this is to get the anchor element which is inside each li element (menu item)
        elementoSinal.classList.add('costumizado-mais');
        var subMenusSecondary = document.getElementById(subMenusPrimary[i].id).querySelectorAll(".sidr-class-dropdown-menu");
        var subMenusSecondaryCount = subMenusSecondary.length;
        console.log("SubMenusSecondaryCount = " + subMenusSecondaryCount);
        elementoSinal.onclick = function() {myFunction(subMenusSecondary,elementoSinal)};
    }

}


function myFunction(lista,sinal) {

   var nElementos = lista.length;

   for (var i = 0; i < nElementos; i++) {
     console.log("ID: " + lista[i].id);
     if( lista[i].classList.contains("sidr-class-dropdown-menu") ){
      lista[i].classList.remove("sidr-class-dropdown-menu");
      lista[i].classList.add("is-open");
      sinal.classList.remove('costumizado-mais');
      sinal.classList.add('costumizado-menos');
     }else if ( lista[i].classList.contains("is-open") ){
      lista[i].classList.remove("is-open");
      lista[i].classList.add("sidr-class-dropdown-menu");
      sinal.classList.remove('costumizado-menos');
      sinal.classList.add('costumizado-mais');
     }
   }

}
```

[menu closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL5GF.png)

[menu opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VErOC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery like so:

Let's say the dropdowns you want to subscribe to an event all have the "sub" class.

```
$(".sub").on("click",function(e){console.log(e);})
```